# Downloading PyGame for Python 3.4

Tags: python, pygame

I was hoping to install PyGame on Python 3.4. So far I have downloaded:

*pygame‑1.9.3‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl*

from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
```

I am using WING IDE for this, not sure if they matters or not. When i enter 'import pygame' I am without error. It is only when I enter *pygame.init()* that i get the following error.

```
  File "C:/Users/mount_000/Desktop/CS116/pygame-banans.py", line 3, in <module>
    pygame.init()
builtins.AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'
```

I have read some some articles about extracting the file but not sure exactly how.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's the wrong pygame version. You need the `cp34` version and the bitness of Python and pygame have to match (64 bit pygame for 64 bit Python). Do you know how to use the Windows command-line? You can install pygame in the command-line by entering `py -3.4 -m pip install pygame` (that will download pygame from PyPI and install it specifically for Python 3.4). 
And is there a reason why you use this old Python version? Pygame works with Python 3.6 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was hoping to install PyGame on Python 3.4. So far I have
>   downloaded:
>
> pygame‑1.9.3‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl

The question is, your Python version is 3.4, but you downloaded the cp27 version `.whl` file. The ‘cp27’ is just used for Python 2.7.

You need to download the

> pygame‑1.9.3‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl

or

> pygame‑1.9.3‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you installed PyGame with Python 2.7

> pygame‑1.9.3‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl

install it with Python 3.4!

On Python2.7, try

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Apr  4 2017, 08:47:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
>>> pygame.init()
2017-07-24 09:52:53.759 Python[1067:10041] ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to /var/folders/7s/d087_7dx48n6mdl1ry4hw1s40000gn/T/org.python.python.savedState
(6, 0)
```